# Find the limit : $\lim_{(x,y) \to (+\infty,+\infty)}(x^2+y^2)e^{-(x+y)}$

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus, solution-verification

Evaluate:

$$\lim_{(x,y) \to (+\infty,+\infty)}(x^2+y^2)e^{-(x+y)}$$

---

We have,

$$\begin{align}\lim_{(x,y)\to (\infty,\infty)}\frac{x^2+y^2}{e^{x+y}}&=\lim_{(x,y)\to (\infty,\infty)}\frac{(x+y)^2-2xy}{e^{x+y}}\\
&=\lim_{(x,y)\to (\infty,\infty)} \frac{(x+y)^2}{e^{x+y}}-\lim_{(x,y)\to (\infty,\infty)} \frac{2xy}{e^{x+y}}\\
&=-2\lim_{(x,y)\to (\infty,\infty)} \frac{xy}{e^{x+y}}\\
&=-2 \lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{x}{e^x}\times \lim_{y\to \infty}\frac{y}{e^y}\\
&=0.\end{align}$$

---

I did not work with the limits with two variables.  That's why, I'm not sure I made a rigorous proof.

My question is:

- Is this method mathematically valid?  Are there any non-rigorous steps in my method?

<sub>Thank you.</sub>

Comment: Along the path $x=-y$ the limit is $2x^2 \to\infty$

Comment: There are many issues in what you wrote. Beginning with the first thing, how do you define with $\epsilon$-$\delta$: $\lim\limits_{(x,y) \to (\infty,\infty)} f(x,y) = a$?

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net  Currently, I can not define. I didn't work with $2$ variable limits..

Comment: Do you mean the limit at $+\infty, +\infty$ ?

Comment: @FiMePr yes, sure.

Comment: @lonestudent Ok ! Then, you might find my answer of some use. (Perhaps you could edit your question, to make it more explicit)

Comment: @NinadMunshi : Along your path, if $x\to+\infty$, then $y\to-\infty$, but the OP wants a limit where $x\to+\infty$ and $y\to+\infty$. (The notation can be ambiguous, since sometimes $x\to\infty$ means $x\to\pm\infty$ and sometimes it means $x\to+\infty$. But OP's reasoning with $x/\mathrm{e}^x\to0$, which should be the easy part for OP, only works with $x\to+\infty$.)

Comment: My guess is that the definition should be something like: for all $\varepsilon > 0$, there exist $R_1, R_2$ such that whenever $x \ge R_1$ and $y \ge R_2$, then $|f(x, y) - L| < \varepsilon$.  (Which is equivalent to: for all $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists $R$ such that whenever $x \ge R$ and $y \ge R$, then $|f(x, y) - L| < \varepsilon$.)

Comment: And my proof that the limit in that sense equals 0 would involve the estimate that $|(x^2 + y^2) e^{-(x+y)}| \le |x^2 e^{-x}| + |y^2 e^{-y}|$ if $x, y \ge 0$ - so take some $S$ such that $|x^2 e^{-x}| < \varepsilon / 2$ whenever $x \ge S$ using the single-variable limit $\lim_{x\to \infty} x^2 e^{-x} = 0$, and then set $R := \max(S, 0)$.

Comment: @DanielSchepler Thanks for your comments.

Comment: You should clarify what you mean by $(x,y)\rightarrow (\infty ,\infty)$ and elaborate your change of variables.

Comment: @copper.hat If you had added a little proof verification to your answer, I would accept your answer as the best answer. I guess you were angry with me and deleted the answer.

Comment: @lonestudent I am not angry, just annoyed that you were impatiently asking for help but not answering any of the elaborations asked of you.

Comment: @copper.hat $(x,y )\to (\infty, \infty) $ means, for any $M>0$ , we have $x>M, y>M$. I'm saying what's on my own mind.  I haven't read it somewhere.  This notation was in the original limit.  This is the explanation that I understand. I was caught between chat and question, I missed your comment.

Comment: I wrote it in the chat as well, and referred to my comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution seem fine. Your breaking up of the limits is perfectly valid.

I would have approached this by noting that, by using L'Hôspital twice, we get
$$
\lim_{u\to\infty}\frac{u^2}{e^u}=0\tag1
$$
Then, because $(x,y)$ is eventually in the first quadrant, $(x,y)=r(\cos(\theta),\sin(\theta))$, where $0\le\theta\le\frac\pi2$.
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{x^2+y^2}{(x+y)^2}
&=\frac1{(\cos(\theta)+\sin(\theta))^2}\tag{2a}\\
&=\frac1{2\sin^2\left(\theta+\frac\pi4\right)}\tag{2b}\\[3pt]
&\le1\tag{2c}
\end{align}
$$
Let $u=x+y$, then as $(x,y)\to(\infty,\infty)$, $u\to\infty$.
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{(x,y)\to(\infty,\infty)}\left(x^2+y^2\right)e^{-x-y}
&\le\limsup_{(x,y)\to(\infty,\infty)}\frac{x^2+y^2}{(x+y)^2}\lim_{(x,y)\to(\infty,\infty)}(x+y)^2e^{-x-y}\tag{3a}\\
&\le\sup_{0\le\theta\le\pi/2}\frac1{(\sin(\theta)+\cos(\theta))^2}\lim_{u\to\infty}u^2e^{-u}\tag{3b}\\[3pt]
&=1\cdot0\tag{3c}
\end{align}
$$

---

**Graphical Solution Verification**

The first term on the right side of $\text{(3a)}$ is

[image]

The second term on the right side of $\text{(3a)}$ is

[image]

Thus, as $(x,y)\to(\infty,\infty)$, we have
$$
\overbrace{\frac{x^2+y^2}{(x+y)^2}}^{\le1}\overbrace{(x+y)^2e^{-x-y}\vphantom{\frac{x^2+y^2}{(x+y)^2}}}^{\to0}\to0
$$

Comment: Thank you very much. I will accept your answer.  Would you like to add a little solution-verification to your answer?.

Comment: I think I figured out what you meant by solution-verification. I added that to the top and a graphical verification of my method to the bottom.

Comment: Thank you for details ! (I see your additions) What I mean, can you add to your answer whether the things/attempts I did in my question are valid? I have no teacher.  So I want to know for sure the correctness of my steps/attempts.

Comment: @lonestudent: did you see the first paragraph that was added at the top of the answer? It says that your answer looks fine and what you did is valid. (I also upvoted your question).

Answer (score 2):

Using $x^2+y^2 \le (x+y)^2$ for $x,y>0$ we have $(x^2+y^2)e^{-(x+y)} \le (x+y)^2 e^{-(x+y)}$

So $$\lim_{(x,y)\to(\infty,\infty)} (x^2+y^2)e^{-(x+y)} \le \lim_{(x,y)\to(\infty,\infty)}  (x+y)^2 e^{-(x+y)} = \lim_{u\to\infty} u^2e^{-u} = 0$$

Comment: Well, but my question is different $\ddot \smile$

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you are talking about the limit at $(+\infty, +\infty)$.

If I understood your intent correctly, I think your idea could be made rigorous by using sequences : take any $(x_n, y_n)_n$ that tends to $(+\infty, +\infty)$, and check that the sequence $(x_n^2 + y_n^2)e^{-(x_n+y_n)}$ tends to $0$.

More precisely : you can define the quantities $u_n$ and $v_n$ that correspond to your original idea. Then **use operations on limits to adapt your previous informal ideas.**

For instance, the final steps in your proof would become : $\frac{v_n}{e^{u_n}}= \frac{x_n y_n}{e^{x_n} e^{y_n}} \rightarrow 0$ because $\frac{x_n}{e^{x_n}} \rightarrow 0$ and  $\frac{y_n}{e^{y_n}} \rightarrow 0$.

The general fact I am using here : *If $f$ is a function (possibly with several variables), if $l, a$ are numbers (or $\pm\infty$), then $f(z)$ tends to $l$ when $z$ tends to $a$ **if and only if**, for all sequences $(z_n)$ that tend to $l$ such that $f(z_n)$ is well-defined, $f(z_n)$ tends to $l$ as $n$ tends to infinity.*

This is true even in more than one variable, as long as there are finitely many variables and you are dealing with real or complex numbers (I am not getting into the general topological definition, unless you are really interested).

Answer (score 0):

If we let $x = r\cos\theta,y = r\sin\theta$, then $\theta\in (0,\pi/2),r\to\infty$ as $(x,y)\to(+\infty,+\infty)$. Now
$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(+\infty,+\infty)}(x^2+y^2)e^{-(x+y)} = \lim_{(r,\theta)\to(\infty,\theta_0)}r^2e^{-r(\cos\theta+\sin\theta)}\leq \lim_{(r,\theta)\to(\infty,\theta_0)} r^2e^{-r} =0$$
where $\theta_0\in (0,\pi/2)$. I wonder such expression is valid. The notion $\theta_0$ means that it may not converge to particular value but should be in $(0,\pi/2)$.